# Shell access to GNU Parallel's total number of jobs

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

When invoked with the option --eta, GNU Parallel computes the total number of jobs to be run. Is there any way to make this value available to the shell, perhaps with a replacement string?

This would be useful, among other things, for zero-padding job numbers. For example, if the replacement string for the total number of jobs were {###}, the zero-padding might be done as follows:

```
printf "%0$(printf {###} | wc -m)d" {#}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.

The reason is that to compute the number of jobs GNU Parallel has to build the commands to be executed. And if you are using -X, then the number of jobs depended on the length of the replacement strings, so GNU Parallel does not know the number of jobs when it starts building the first command. Only when all commands are built, does GNU Parallel know how many there are.

To understand why this a problem look at this paradox. Which of these should be correct:

```
$ seq 1000 1010 | parallel -Xj1 -s 17 echo {###} {}
6 1000 1001
6 1002 1003
6 1004 1005
6 1006 1007
6 1008 1009
6 1010
```

Or:

```
$ seq 1000 1010 | parallel -Xj1 -s 17 echo {###} {}
11 1000
11 1001
11 1002
11 1003
11 1004
11 1005
11 1006
11 1007
11 1008
11 1009
11 1010
```

You can argue that both of them are correct.